# Generate Set<domainType> Java types from XSD "unbounded" complexTypes using JAXB

Tags: xsd, jaxb, xsd-validation, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have a requirement to generate POJO using JAXB from the following XSD (partial). The elements is a collection of domain type and I want this to be `Set<domainType>`. I get `List<domainType>` in generated pojo with the following XSD. How can I instruct JAXB to generate this type as Set instead?

```
<xs:element name="sampleSetElements">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="elements" type="xyz:domainType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />            
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `property/@collectionType` customization. See docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148590).